# ansible copy file based on the group name

Tags: ansible

I have a task which copies a default script file to the destination:

```
- name: copy keepalive state script
  copy:
    src: 'keepalived.state.sh'
    dest: /usr/local/bin/keepalived.state.sh
    mode: '0755'
    owner: root
    group: root
```

And now I want to have scripts based on the group that the host is in, so I changed the task to this:

```
- name: copy keepalive state script
  copy:
    src: '{{keepalived_state_script_file}}'
    dest: /usr/local/bin/keepalived.state.sh
    mode: '0755'
    owner: root
    group: root
  vars:
    keepalived_state_script_file: "{{ lookup('first_found', dict(files=['keepalived/' + item + '.state.sh', 'keepalive.state.sh'])) }}"
  with_items: "{{group_names}}"
```

so now for a host inside the `application` group, if I put the `application.state.sh` file inside the `keepalived` directory, it will copy this file instead of default `keepalived.state.sh`, but If my host is a member of more than one group like this:

```
[application]
host1

[dc1]
host1
```

this task will first checks the `application` group and copies the `application.state.sh` then checks the `dc1` group and since there is no `dc1.state.sh` it will copy the default script file which is `keepalived.state.sh`.

Considering I will use only one script file per host no matter how many groups that host is member of, how can I fix the problem so that I can get the customized script instead of the default script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is way too complicated. You try to invent a feature, that Ansibles has already implemented: group vars.

Put the files `application.yml` and `dc1.yml` in the `group_vars` directory.

For the `application` group you set one value:

```
files_to_copy:
  - file1
  - file2
```

And for the `dc1` group you set other values:

```
files_to_copy:
  - file3
  - file4
```

And in your playbook you iterate just over the `files_to_copy` variable. Ansible will take care, that every host gets the right variable based on the group membership.